# Is an ANOVA or Kruskal Wallis test an appropriate test for this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am working on a research project currently to determine whether the difference in uninsured rates between Blacks, Whites, Hispanic, and Asians are  significant. I am converting the data from the CPS into proportions. What would the appropriate test be to determine whether these proportions are significantly different.

Example Data Below:

From 2020

White: 19,381/247,869

Black: 4,118/42,991

Asian: 1,240/19,905

Hispanic: 10,122/60,517

How would I be able to determine that pw≠pb≠pa≠ph

Comment: No. Chi-square test.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to give a definitive answer with the limited
information provided. If you're looking at two binomial
proportions hoping for 80% power detecting a difference
in proportions of 0.05, you'd need about 1100 subjects
in each group. I mention this in particular because
I see much larger samples in your data above.

I have
no idea what differences in proportions are too small
to be of interest, so I guessed $0.05 = 5\%$ would be
of interest.

You could do a chi-squared test with many ethnic groups,
and counts of insured and uninsured. But if you found
overall differences among groups in that test, I'm guessing you'd want
to look at comparisons *ad hoc* two at a time.

If I've guessed wrong and this answer is not useful, please use that as a basis
for a more carefully targeted question.

Printout from a recent release of Minitab:

```
Power and Sample Size 

Test for Two Proportions

Testing comparison p = baseline p (versus ≠)
Calculating power for baseline p = 0.25
α = 0.05


               Sample  Target
 Comparison p    Size   Power  Actual Power
          0.2    1464     0.9      0.900057
          0.2    1094     0.8      0.800095

The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]